# How to found template in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

How I determine which template is responsible for processing node of page with this URL: mysite.com/node/node-number/edit ?
I think, that Drupal find the template of edit in this files:

```
page-node-edit.tpl.php
page-node- node-number.tpl.php
page-node.tpl.php
page.tpl.php
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to repost the same question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Devel module provides a really neat way of finding suggestions for template files. For Drupal 7 (and 8?) this functionality is moved to a separate module ("Theme Developer"), but for D6 I'm pretty certain it is included in Devel: https://www.drupal.org/project/devel

Here's a video from Lullabot showing how to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0z9FRWPfIOU

By the way: Moving to a newer version of Drupal is a good idea.